# How to trigger 'return' when specific output given

Tags: python, pymysql

I'm developing a authentication script in Python. I need PyMySQL to check if user exists, how can I do that?

I read the documention but didn't find answer to my question.

```
def check():
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                        user='user',
                        password='passwd',
                        db='db',
                        charset='utf8mb4',
                        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    userexist = # PyMySQL check code here
    if userexist=='True':
       return 'good'
```

Comment: In order to get better answers you should show what you tried so far.

Comment: I tried ```cursor.fetchone()``` but It gave me all of user info.. So I'm looking for specific output when user exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want to check for the pymysql user or a user from the database. This code will address both instances.
pymysql will raise an exception: `pymysql.err.OperationalError` if the user does not exist. You therefore need a try, except clause like this:

```
def check():
    try:
        connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                     user='user',
                                     password='passwd',
                                     db='db',
                                     charset='utf8mb4',
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    except pymysql.err.OperationalError:
        print('User with entered connection credentials does not exists')
        return False
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("select...") # Fill with your select statement
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            if result is None:
                connection.close()
                return False
    finally:
        connection.close()
    return 'good'
```